# Create view with two reference to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `persons` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 CREATE TABLE `marriage` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `place` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `spouse1` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `spouse2` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `sp1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `persons` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `sp2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `persons` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now I would like to create the view with place of marriage and full names of both spouse. How can I do it? I tried like this (obviously not correctly):

```
CREATE 
  ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
  DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 VIEW `mar` AS
select 
    `marriage`.`place` AS `place`,
    `persons`.`first_name` AS `first_name_sp1`,
    `persons`.`first_name` AS `first_name_sp2`
from
    (`persons`
    join `marriage`)
where
    ((`marriage`.`spouse1` = `persons`.`id`)
        and (`marriage`.`spouse2` = `persons`.`id`))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select that you want needs to mention `persons` twice:

```
select m.place, p1.first_name as first_name_sp1,
       p2.first_name as first_name_sp2
from marriage m join
     persons p1
     on m.spouse1 = p1.id join
     persons p2
     on m.spouse2 = p2.id;
```

You can put this in a view just by putting `create view mar as` before it.

And note the use of table aliases to distinguish between the two tables.  This is a case where table aliases are required.  However, they often make a query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

JOIN to Persons Twice, using aliases, and I would suggest replacing the `WHERE` joins with an `ANSI JOIN`:

```
select 
    m.place AS place,
    p1.first_name` AS first_name_sp1,
    p2.first_name AS first_name_sp2
from
    marriage m
     INNER JOIN persons p1
     ON m.spouse1 = p1.id
     INNER JOIN persons p2
     ON m.spouse2 = p2.id
```